# How to copy data from unsigned int to ulong4 in CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, memcpy

.h file:

```
#define VECTOR_SIZE 1024
```

.cpp file:

```
int main ()
{
    unsigned int* A;
    A = new unsigned int [VECTOR_SIZE];

    CopyToDevice (A);
}
```

.cu file:

```
void CopyToDevice (unsigned int *A)
{
    ulong4 *UA
    unsigned int VectorSizeUlong4 = VECTOR_SIZE / 4;
    unsigned int VectorSizeBytesUlong4 = VectorSizeUlong4 * sizeof(ulong4);

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&UA, VectorSizeBytesUlong4 );

    // how to use cudaMemcpy to copy data from A to UA?

    // I tried to do the following but it gave access violation error:
    for (int i=0; i<VectorSizeUlong4; ++i)
    {
        UA[i].x = A[i*4 + 0];
        UA[i].y = A[i*4 + 1];
        UA[i].z = A[i*4 + 2];
        UA[i].w = A[i*4 + 3];
    }
    // I also tried to copy *A to device and then work on it instead going back to CPU to access *A every time but this did not work again
}
```

[image]

Comment: Total size of source and destination are not the same in your code. Do you want to perform an element-to-element copy? Even in this case, the number of elements in the source and the destination don't match.

Comment: Crude method is to copy to device memory of equal size first(say `temp`) and then write your own kernel to copy from `temp` to `UA` one by one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CUDA `ulong4` is a 16 byte aligned structure defined as

```
struct __builtin_align__(16) ulong4
{
  unsigned long int x, y, z, w;
};
```

this means that the stream of four consecutive 32 bit unsigned source integers you want to use to populate a stream of `ulong4` are the same size. The simplest solution is contained right in the text on the image you posted - just cast (either implicitly or explicitly) the `unsigned int` pointer to a `ulong4` pointer, use `cudaMemcpy`directly on the host and device memory, and pass the resulting device pointer to whatever kernel function you have that requires a `ulong4` input. Your device transfer function could look something like:

```
ulong4* CopyToDevice (unsigned int* A)
{
    ulong4 *UA, *UA_h;
    size_t VectorSizeUlong4 = VECTOR_SIZE / 4;
    size_t VectorSizeBytesUlong4 = VectorSizeUlong4 * sizeof(ulong4);

    cudaMalloc( (void**)&UA, VectorSizeBytesUlong4);
    UA_h = reinterpret_cast<ulong4*>(A); // not necessary but increases transparency
    cudaMemcpy(UA, UA_h, VectorSizeBytesUlong4);

    return UA;   
}
```

[Usual disclaimer: written in browser, not tested or compiled, use at own risk]

Comment: I think  `unsigned long` is typically 64 bits (8 bytes) on a 64-bit OS machine.  I realize it's implementation dependent, so I'm speaking in general terms.  On a 64 bit linux machine, in my experience, `sizeof(ulong4)` would be 32, and would size-wise be equivalent to eight 32 bit quantities.  Which for me begs the question when casting from `unsigned int` to `ulong4`, do you simply want to extend 4 quantities, or do you want to pack 8 quantities into a `ulong4`?

Comment: @RobertCrovella: At least on MS platforms (which is admittedly all I checked), unsigned long int is a 32 bit quantity on both 32 and 64 bit host operating systems. If it turns out that ulong4 is a 64 bit quantity, then a copy/assign kernel probably makes the most sense.

Comment: `UA_h = reinterpret_cast<ulong4>(A);` gave error: `cast to type "ulong4" is not allowed`. So I changed it to `UA_h = reinterpret_cast<ulong4*>(A);`

Comment: @Shibli: That was a typo - as I said in the disclaimer, I wrote this code in the broswer

Answer (score 2):

This should raise all alarm bells:

```
cudaMalloc( (void**)&UA, VectorSizeBytesUlong4 );
// ...
UA[i].x = A[i*4 + 0];
```

You are allocating UA on the device and then use it in host code. Don't ever do that. You will need to use `cudaMemcpy` to copy arrays to the device. [This tutorial](http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~lindsey/cuda/project2/cuda.html) shows you a basic program that uses cudaMemcpy to copy things over. The length argument to cudaMemcpy is the length of your array in bytes. And in your case that is `VECTOR_SIZE * sizeof(unsigned int)`.